# Jackson's polymorphic serialization / deserialization AND custom serializer / deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'va an OID interface that can be implemented by many concrete types:

```java
public interface OID {
}
public abstract class OIDBase
           implements OID {
   private String _id;
}
public class MyOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    public MyOID() {
        // default no-args constructor
    }
}
public class MyOtherOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    public MyOtherOID() {
        // default no-args constructor
    }
}
```

Now I've an object with two fields, one defined using the abstract interface type (OID) and the other defined using a concrete type (MyOID)

```java
public class MyBean {
    private OID _absOid;
    private MyOID _concreteOid;

    public MyBean(final OID absOid,final MyOID concreteOid) {
        _absOid = absOid;
        _concreteOid = concreteOid;
    }
}
```

I want to use jackson to serialize / deserialize the fields differently whether they're defined using the abstract interface type or the concrete type:

```java
{
    "_absOid": {
                    "type" : "MyOtherOID",
                    "id" : "__an_id__"
               },
    "_concreteOid" : "__another_id___"
}
```

Beware that `_absOid` is serialized including type information (polymorphic serialization) and `_concreteOid` is serialized as text

To do so, I've annotated the OID interface as:

```java
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(MyOID.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(MyOtherOID.class)
})
public interface OID {
}
```

and assigned a type id to each concrete types:

```java
@JsonTypeName("MyOID")
public class MyOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    ...
}
@JsonTypeName("MyOtherOID")
public class MyOtherOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    ...
}
```

finally the abstract-defined field at the container bean is annotated to make jackson include the type info:

```java
public class MyBean {
    @JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
                  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                  property = "type")
    private OID _absOid;

    private MyOID _concreteOid;
}
```

so far, so good, BUT in order to serialize differently if the field is defined using the abstract type (OID) and if the field is defined using the concrete type (MyOID), I have to create a custom serializer:

First annotate the concrete types to use the serializer / deserializer:

```java
@JsonTypeName("MyOID")
@JsonSerialize(using=OIDSerializer.class) @JsonDeserialize(using=OIDDeSerializer.class)
public class MyOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    ...
}
@JsonTypeName("MyOtherOID")
@JsonSerialize(using=OIDSerializer.class) @JsonDeserialize(using=OIDDeSerializer.class)
public class MyOtherOID 
     extends OIDBase {
    ...
}
```

... the serializer / deserializer code:

```java
public static class OIDSerializer 
            extends JsonSerializer<OID> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final OID value,
                          final JsonGenerator jgen,
                          final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        // **** used when serializing a concrete type
        jgen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(final OID value, 
                                  final JsonGenerator jgen,
                                  final SerializerProvider provider,
                                  final TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        // **** used when serializing a polymorphic type
        // guess the type id
        WritableTypeId typeId = typeSer.typeId(value,JsonToken.START_OBJECT);

        // type prefix
        typeSer.writeTypePrefix(jgen,
                                typeId);

        // object
        jgen.writeFieldName("id");
        jgen.writeString(value.toString());

        // type suffix 
        typeId.wrapperWritten = !jgen.canWriteTypeId();
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(jgen,
                                typeId);
    }
}
```

The **PROBLEM** arises **when de-serializing** the json string, I've used the following custom deserializer:

```java
public static class OIDDeSerializer 
            extends StdDeserializer<OID> { 

    public MyOIDDeSerializer() { 
        super(MyOID.class); 
    } 
    @Override
    public OID deserialize(final JsonParser jp,
                           final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {            
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp); 

        // [1] - Read the id depending on the serialized format
        String oidStr = null;           
        // text node > concrete oid impl serialized as [value]
        if (node.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.STRING) {
            oidStr = ((TextNode)node).asText();
        }
        // oid=value > abstract oid impl serialized as {typeId=[type],oid={value]} 
        else {
            ObjectNode objNode = (ObjectNode)node;
            oidStr = objNode.findValue("id").asText();
        }

        // [2] - Read tye type id 
        String typeId = objNode.findValue("type").asText()

        // PROBLEM!!!!!!
        // how get the type from the typeId in order to create the concrete instance
        // how access the type resolver????
        Class<? extends OID> oidType = RESOLVE TYPE FROM THE ID
        return oidType.newInstance();
    }
}
```

So the **problem** is **how to access the type from the type id resolving** at the custom **deserializer**???

Comment: I'm no expert on Jackson but I'd probably try one of the following: 1. try to read the annotations  on `OID` and get the class from the annotation matching the type id or 2. instead of using a type id I'd try to use the fully qualified class name and upon serialization it would be down to a simple `Class.forName(fqcn)`.  - You are probably looking for a way to do variant 1. without having to scan the annotations yourself though, aren't you?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, you're right in the solution, the problem is how to access the annotations info: as sachin pointed, Jackson uses an annotation introspector that does precisely that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
AnnotationIntrospector annotationInspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotatedClass annotatedClass = AnnotatedClass.constructWithoutSuperTypes(OID.class,
                new ObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig());
List<NamedType> subtypes = annotationInspector.findSubtypes(annotatedClass);

for(NamedType type: subtypes){
    if(type.getType().getName().contains(typeId)){
        return type.getClass().newInstance();   
    }

}
```

Comment: Sachin you're the one! thank you 
:.. i'll post the complete solution just for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 1):

The **serializer** MUST be aware of the fact that the field maybe serialized alongside with the type info (when the field is declared using an abstract type)
... so the serializer MUST override serializeWithType()

```java
public static class OIDSerializer 
            extends JsonSerializer<OID> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final OID value,
                          final JsonGenerator jgen,
                          final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.asString());
    }
    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(final OID value,
                                  final JsonGenerator jgen,
                                  final SerializerProvider provider,
                                  final TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        // guess the type id
        WritableTypeId typeId = typeSer.typeId(value,JsonToken.START_OBJECT);

        // type prefix
        typeSer.writeTypePrefix(jgen,
                                typeId);

        // object
        jgen.writeFieldName("idStr");
        jgen.writeString(value.asString());

        // type suffix 
        typeId.wrapperWritten = !jgen.canWriteTypeId();
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(jgen,
                                typeId);
        }
}
```

On the other hand, the **deserializer**'s interesting part is where the type is resolved from the typeId using @Sachin's pointed solution at _oidTypeFromId() method in the following code:

```java
public static class OIDDeSerializer 
             extends StdDeserializer<OID> 
         implements ContextualDeserializer {

    // property being deserialized
    private BeanProperty _property;

    public OIDDeSerializer() { 
        super(OID.class); 
    }      
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext ctxt,
                                                final BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        _property = property;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public OID deserialize(final JsonParser parser,
                             final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
                                                                       JsonProcessingException {
        String idStr = null;                        // the oid
        Class<? extends OID> oidType = null;      // the oid type

        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser); 

        // [1] - Read the id depending on the serialized format
        // text node > concrete oid impl serialized as [value]
        if (node.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.STRING) {
            idStr = ((TextNode)node).asText();
            oidType = (Class<? extends OID>)_property.getType().getRawClass();
        }
        // oid=value > abstract oid impl serialized as {typeId=[type],oid={value]} 
        else {
            ObjectNode objNode = (ObjectNode)node;
            idStr = objNode.findValue("idStr").asText();
            String typeId = objNode.findValue("typeId").asText();
            oidType = (Class<? extends OID>)_oidTypeFromId(ctxt.getAnnotationIntrospector(),
                                                                ctxt.getConfig(),
                                                                typeId);
        }            
        // [2] - Get the oid type
        OID outOid = ReflectionUtils.createInstanceFromString(oidType,idStr);
        return outOid;
    }

    private Class<? extends OID> _oidTypeFromId(final AnnotationIntrospector annotationIntrospector,
                                                final DeserializationConfig cfg,
                                                final String typeId) {
        Class<? extends OID> outType = null;
        AnnotatedClass annotatedClass = AnnotatedClassResolver.resolveWithoutSuperTypes(cfg,
                                                                                        OID.class);
        List<NamedType> subtypes = annotationIntrospector.findSubtypes(annotatedClass);
        for (NamedType type: subtypes){
            if (type.getName().equals(typeId)){
                outType = (Class<? extends OID>)type.getType();   
            }
        }
        return outType;
    }
}
```